# PdfPCell Number ontop of image

Tags: itext, pdfptable

I would like to know if it is possible to put text on top of a image in a PDFPCell on ITextSharp.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to add text to an image?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-image) More specifically of **approach 2** in my answer to that question: use a [cell event](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/cell-event) to add text to the `TEXTCANVAS` of the `PdfPCell`. Please read [the documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) before posting a question.

Comment: Thanks Bruno Lowagie.